# Why is my question locked?

Tags: support

I received a notification that my question is locked. Is there a way to know exactly why this happened and who was responsible for it? It seems the question was doing well in terms of upvotes and then all of a sudden it was locked.

Comment: It was locked after an edit war. I was going to comment but then it seemed as though the people involved had worked it out, so I just locked it to stop anyone else editing it further.

Comment: Thanks @curiousdannii, I suspected that might be the case but then again, I wast not sure since I have had so many posts closed or moved...

Comment: It would have been better to comment at the time, sorry.